# Smoothing using kernel and loess in R

Tags: r, logging, kernel, smoothing, loess

I am trying to smooth my data set, using kernel or loess smoothing method. But, They are all not clear or not what I want. Several questions are the followings.
My x data is "conc" and y data is "depth", which is ex. cm.

1) Kernel smooth

`k <- kernel("daniell", 150)`

`plot(k)`

`K <- kernapply(conc, k)`

`plot(conc~depth)`

`lines(K, col = "red")`

Here, my data is smoothed by frequency=150. This means that every data point is averaged by neighboring (right and left) 150 data points? What "daniell" means? I could not find what it means online.

2) Loess smooth

`p<-qplot(depth, conc, data=total)`

`p1 <- p + geom_smooth(method = "loess", size = 1, level=0.95)`

Here, what is the default of loess smooth function? If I want to smooth my data with frequency=150 like above case (moving average by every 150 data point), how can I modify this code?

3) To show y-axis with log scale, I put "log10(conc)", instead of "conc", and it worked. But, I cannot change the y-axis tick label. I tried to use "scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,1e3))" in my code to show axis tick labe like 10^0, 10^1, 10^2..., but did not work. 
Please answer my questions. Thanks a lot for your help.

Sum

Comment: Regarding `loess` I think that the `loess` package just supports tri-cubic weight functions. And `ggplot` seems to use the package (see [link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_smooth.html)). Probably it's not easy to switch to some other weight function than tri-cubic. However, in order to control the number of points used for each fit you can use the parameter `span` (see `loess` package help).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I applied the parameter span for loess smoothing. Would you let me know how to show y-axis tick label like 10^0, 10^1, 10^2...??